# Бот не реагирует на команду

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Ссылка на архив [Bot.py](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/P88U/2S9yiMtNz)

Учу питон третий день, сильно не ругайтесь.

Нужно чтобы бот спросил "есть ли 18?", отреагировал на ответ "Да","Нет" и иной.
Сейчас он обрабатывает else, еще до того как я успел что-то написать. В прошлых версиях кода он не отвечал командами на Да и Нет, а просто говорил "Я не знаю что на это ответить", причем брал он этот ответ из другого блока команд. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'good':
            ...

        elif call.data == 'bad':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Не очень", reply_markup=None)

            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ответь мне на один вопрос:")
            markup = types.ForceReply()
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Есть 18?", reply_markup=markup)

            @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
            def text_handler(message):
                text = message.text.lower()
            if call.message.text == "Да":
                photo = open ('photos\love.png')
                bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, photo, caption='Рад помочь)')
            elif call.message.text == "Нет":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Это конец нашего диалога...")
            else:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Не хочешь - не отвечай, ладно")

        elif call.data == 'cat':

            ...
```

"Блок выше" и кнопки, на которые нужно ответить.

```
@bot.message_handler()
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'ОК':
            ...
        elif message.text == 'Чел ты':
 
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не очень", callback_data='bad')
 
            markup.add(item1, item2)
 
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично, сам как?', reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == 'Понятно':
            ...
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю, что на это ответить ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import config


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TelegramAPI)

keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() #наша клавиатура
key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes') #кнопка «Да»
keyboard.add(key_yes) #добавляем кнопку в клавиатуру
key_no= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no')
keyboard.add(key_no)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет!\n Тебе есть 18 лет?", reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes": #call.data это callback_data, которую мы указали при объявлении кнопки
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Отлично')
    elif call.data == "no":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Здесь только с 18 лет')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```